# GitHub import repository from Visual Studio Team Service does not work, why?

Tags: git, github, import, migration, azure-devops

I tried to migrate a repository from Visual Studio Team Service (VSTS) to GitHub by simply going to Github under the plus (+) drop down box. There is the "import repository" button. The repository clone URL and credentials were required and it usually worked (e.g. GitLab) but not for VSTS.

Only this message appeared:
"No source repositories were detected at . Please check the URL and try again."

How to import/migrate from VSTS to GitHub?

BTW, the "Enable alternate authentication credentials" are enabled in VSTS.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as you, so I ended up importing it using the Git command line.

I followed the instructions from https://help.github.com/articles/importing-a-git-repository-using-the-command-line/ copied below:

1. Create an empty repo in GitHub
2. Open Git command line
3. Navigate to an empty directory
4. Make a 'bare' clone of the repo (replace URL with your clone URL from VSTS):

   ```
   git clone --bare https://external-host.com/extuser/repo.git
   ```
5. Go into directory (replace repo.git with your directory name):

   ```
   cd repo.git
   ```
6. Push cloned repo using 'mirror' option (replace URL with your GitHub repo URL):

   ```
   git push --mirror https://github.com/ghuser/repo.git
   ```
7. Remove the temporary local repository (replace repo.git with your directory name):

   ```
   cd ..
   rm -rf repo.git
   ```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I  solved it by pointing at the root of the VSTS repository (e.g: myrepo.visualstudio.com) instead of passing a specific project directory. GitHub will ask automatically for which project you want to import.

Answer (score 1):

These steps work fine for me:

1. Enable alternate authentication credentials and specify user name and password
2. Go to a repository of your VSTS (Code=>Files), click Clone to get the HTTPS URL.
3. Go to Github=>Import repository
4. Type repository URL (step 2)
5. Type alternate authentication credentials (step 1) when it asks for credential

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I have done and it did not work?

Comment: @VitaliDettling Try it with another repository and check the result. On the other hand, could you record your steps (video) and share it here?

Comment: I also couldn't import a VS repo into Github :(

Comment: @ClaudiuConstantin What's the detail error message?

Comment: The same as @VitaliDettling stated above: "No source repositories were detected at [...]. Please check the URL and try again"